# Assign dynamic value to an Input Field in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, input, alert

I have an input field and I want to assign it a value dynamically fetched from DB. I will use that value later in a script. Here is my code below

```
<div data-ng-model="DashboardCounterItems">
<div data-ng-repeat="cItem in DashboardCounterItems">
<input type ="hidden" id ="myInput" value = {{cItem.dbMeetings.length}} />
</div>
</div>
```

Here {{cItem.dbMeetings.length}} is fetched from DB and assigned to myInput. Further when I check the value of this input in alert in script below, I get **{{cItem.dbMeetings.length}}** message instead of the value within it.

```
<script>
var iLenthv = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
alert(iLenthv);
</script>
```

Any help how can I do it. Or any other better way. I will really appreciate it.

Comment: So I'm not familiar with server-side JS, which I'm assuming this is (angular?), but for some language, like Coldfusion, you have to specify that you want the server-side engine to evaluate your variables. In Coldfusion, that's a `#variable#` wrapped in a  `<cfoutput>` tag. Outside of this tag, it simply appears as #variable#, rather than being evaluated.

Comment: When I use it like this 
<input type ="hidden" id ="myInput" value = "THIS VALUE" />
The same alert gives me "THIS VALUE" as an output. I don't know why it does not give dynamic value output

Comment: <div data-ng-model="DashboardCounterItems">
<div data-ng-repeat="cItem in DashboardCounterItems">
{{cItem.dbMeetings.length}} 
</div>
</div>

Also when I run this code, it gives the value of the item

Comment: well sounds like your templating library ain't running.

Comment: Also not sure why you are using an id inside an element that repeats. An id is singular item, not multiple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your JS code will execute before DB data retrieval, can you check JS code within the **setTimeout()** Method?

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        var iLenthv = document.getElementById("myInput").getAttribute("value");
        alert(iLenthv);
    }, 3000); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.getAttribute()` to get the value from a html attribute

```
function myFunction() {
var iLenthv = document.getElementById("myInput").getAttribute("value"); 
alert(iLenthv);
}
```

Hope it's helpfull

Comment: Hi, It didn't work

Comment: then @MirzaBilal try this var iLenthv = {{cItem.dbMeetings.length}};

Answer (score 0):

So we have to track the client side actual value, **after the document is loaded**. Would you adapt this piece of code and take a look at the console ?

```html
<div data-ng-model="DashboardCounterItems">
  <div data-ng-repeat="cItem in DashboardCounterItems">
    <input type="hidden" id="myInput" value={{cItem.dbMeetings.length}} />
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  const test = () => {
    var iLenthv = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    console.log("value:",iLenthv);
  };

  window.onload = test;
</script>
```